# How to call jQuery on render of the rich:panel

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I have a generic jQuery function which aligns the given component to the center of the page.

Now my page has a rich:panel which must be center aligned. I would have done that by some CSS, but is there a way to call javascript method once the rich:panel is rendered or loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can do something like :

```
<rich:panel id="richPanelId">    
</rich:panel>

<rich:jQuery selector="#richPanelId" timing="onload" query="yourMethod()" />
```